# Can PHP submit an HTML form after a timer expires?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Is it possible in PHP to `POST` a form after certain time is elapsed?? I am creating a test section in my website for students where they will be giving answers to MCQs. When the time is finished the results should be posted to the next page via `<form action="">` immediately.

Please tell me if I can have any other options to achieve the same.

I am not in the favor of javascript because I will be having dozens of students and all may not have javascript installed on their computer.

Edit to add my code, including the JavaScript from the answer below:

This isn't working:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.forms['test_form'].post();
    }, 2000);
    </script>
</head>

<?php

define("HOST", "localhost"); // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "admin"); // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", "admin"); // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "test"); // The database name.
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
//some PHP code wil com here...
?>

<body>
    <form action="test_submit.php" method="post" name="test_form">
        <label>This is Question #1:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="ans1" id="ans1">Answer1</input>
        <input type="radio" name="ans2" id="ans2">Answer2</input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not forwarding the page to test_submit.php after 2 seconds as I expect...

Comment: You would probably want to do that with JavaScript.

Comment: There's no other way than JavaScript for this. You can't do it with PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer is no.  PHP is a server-side language with no ability to control the client (e.g. the browser).

The only way you can do what you want is by using JavaScript.  JavaScript allows you to control the flow of forms, including making them submit.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.forms['form_name'].submit();
}, 1000);
```

Where `form_name` is your form, and 1000 is the time to delay the post in milliseconds (i.e. 1000 = 1 second).

If your form doesn't have a name (but has an id) you can also do this, using DOM:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('form_id').submit();
}, 1000);
```

Where `form_id` is your form's id attribute.

Comment: what's the diffeerence between setInterval and setTimeout ?

Comment: `setTimeout` executes the callback a single time.  `setInterval` executes indefinitely (until the interval is cleared), periodically per the delay specified.

Comment: is that it what i have to write in my page or does it requires some other parameters as well?

Comment: That's pretty much all you'll need.  Try it out.

Comment: Use `.submit()`, not `.post()`

Comment: I used `document.getElementById('form_id').submit();` and it worked... Thanks a ton!!

Comment: but does it `POST` ??? I mean will I be able to use the values of radio buttons on the landing page???

Comment: It uses the `action` defined in the `form` element.  If it is `action="post"` then `form.submit()` will do a post.

Comment: does it affect it in any way if i place the JavaScript in body instead of header? because I am already starting a secure session in the header.

Comment: In modern browsers, it won't make a difference.

Comment: when I'm placing this: `<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"></input>`, the javascript timer is not working... what's the problem???

Comment: The problem is that your id is "submit", which is overriding the function `document.forms['form_name'].submit`, which is now a reference to your submit button instead.  Change the id to something else and it should work fine.